# How to install Ubuntu in a netbook, but keeping the original win7 installation in storage

Tags: ubuntu, windows

I have a Samsung N210 netbook. It has windows 7, starter edition.

I´ve tried the latest Ubuntu version using a pendrive and loved it so far.

**I would like to install it in my netbook, but I would also like to keep all my installation** in case something goes wrong (or I don´t like it after using it extensively), and  want to get bak to my win7 install (wich is the original software, that came with the samsung and I have all original updates there).

Is there a way to create a mirror and store it in an external storage drive?

Comment: You can create what's called a dual boot system. This is where you're presented with a GUI during boot-up and you can select between the 2 different OSes installed on the box. Google for "dual boot ubuntu windows" and you'll find what you seek.

Comment: I think you are looking for this http://askubuntu.com/q/1366/169736

Comment: Yup! Thanks!! Didn´t know that site even existed! (I´m such a linux n00b!)